# Pass unique variable to the onClick function when creating a set of entries

Tags: reactjs, onclicklistener

I am trying to send out a unique key in ReactJS for every Card so when I click on it, I can perform some operation with the word like for example remove the entry from a database using Flask. The current setup as shown below only renders the last key of elements to all the cards which makes sense but I cant find another approach to the same.

```
for ( var key in elements) {    
        items.push(
            <Card>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>
                        {key}
                        <Button className='btn-simple btn-icon btn-round xButton' color='danger' onClick={() => this.NotLearnt(key)}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes}/></Button>
                    </CardTitle>
                    <CardText className="meaning">{elements[key]}</CardText>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        )
    }
```

Basically, what I want is that if I have a dictionary like {'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':C} I want 'a' to be passed when I click on the first card and not 'c' which is the last key

EDIT: As answered by Shubham, using let over var reduces the scope of the variable and hence only relevant value is passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of closure and can be fixed by using `let` instead of `var` for key declaration which makes the scope of key to be restricted to the for loop block

```
for ( let key in elements) {    
    items.push(
        <Card>
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>
                    {key}
                    <Button className='btn-simple btn-icon btn-round xButton' color='danger' onClick={() => this.NotLearnt(key)}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes}/></Button>
                </CardTitle>
                <CardText className="meaning">{elements[key]}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    )
}
```